# Como fazer loop dentro do foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, plugin-wordpress

Estou com dificuldade para fazer o código rodar.

Tenho a variável `$posts_metas` que pode estar vazia ou ter um array, depende do que o usuário já cadastrou no DB.

Tenho também a variavel `$uls`que contem urls das imagens que o usuário selecionou.

Estou tentando fazer algumas verificações antes de salvar no DB, veja comentários no codigo abaixo:

```
add_action( 'save_post', function ($post_id) {

if (isset($_POST['my_image_URL'])){ //se existem imagens selecionadas

        $urls = $_POST['my_image_URL']; // variavel urls recebe as urls das imagens

        $posts_metas = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my-image-for-post' ); // busca no DB posts metas onde a coluna  meta_key sejam = "my-image-for-post" e retorna as urls

        if ($posts_metas === ''){   //se posts metas retornou vazio 

            foreach ($urls as $url){ 

                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'my-image-for-post',$url ); // apenas cadastra todas urls... ate aqui quando o DB esta vazio cadastra corretamente as urls             

                }
            }       

        }else{ 

            foreach ($urls as $url){                
                foreach( $posts_metas as $value ) {
                    if($value != $url){ 
                        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'my-image-for-post',$url );                
                    }elseif($value === $url ){
                        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my-image-for-post', $url );
                    }else{
                        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'my-image-for-post',$url );    
                    }               
                }
            }

        }




});
```

No `else` se já existir alguma meta_key para o post com o valor 'my-image-for-post' então tem alguma url cadastrada.

Estou tentando executar as 2 seguintes condições:

1ª se todos valores cadastrados são diferentes da nova url  ou se a url não existe no DB deve add a url.

2ª se o valor da url é identico a alguma url já cadastrada deve somente atualizar

Acontece que depois do `else`, não estou conseguindo acertar o foreach e o loop

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: Já pensou em mudar a lógica? Nesses casos é melhor excluir tudo e inserir apenas o que foi passado. Se for validar caso a casa, a complexidade ciclomática aumenta demais. Se realizar o processo linearmente, fica bem simples.

Comment: foi a saida mesmo, refiz tudo, deixei apenas `delete_post_meta` e `add_post_meta` na action e o restante fiz com jquery. Obrigada @GabrielHeming